# JSON data formatting using Python

Tags: python, json, dictionary, format, key

I am trying to change the JSON format using python. The received message has some key-value pairs and needs to change certain key names before forwarding the message.
for normal key-value pairs, I have used "data. pop" method, data["newkey"]=data.pop("oldkey") .
But it got complicated with nested key-values. This is just a part of big file that needs to be convrted.
How to convert this

```
{
"atrk1": "form_varient",
    "atrv1": "red_top",
    "atrt1": "string",
      "atrk2": "ref",
    "atrv2": "XPOWJRICW993LKJD",
    "atrt2": "string"
}
```

into this?

```
"attributes": {
        "form_varient": {
            "value": "red_top",
            "type": "string"
        },
        "ref": {
            "value": "XPOWJRICW993LKJD",
            "type": "string"
        }
    }
```

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the keys gonna be in the same format you can do something like this.

```
 d = {
    "ev": "contact_form_submitted",
    "et": "form_submit",
    "id": "cl_app_id_001",
    "uid": "cl_app_id_001-uid-001",
    "mid": "cl_app_id_001-uid-001",
    "t": "Vegefoods - Free Bootstrap 4 Template by Colorlib",
    "p": "http://shielded-eyrie-45679.herokuapp.com/contact-us",
    "l": "en-US",
    "sc": "1920 x 1080",
    "atrk1": "form_varient",
    "atrv1": "red_top",
    "atrt1": "string",
      "atrk2": "ref",
    "atrv2": "XPOWJRICW993LKJD",
    "atrt2": "string",
      "uatrk1": "name",
    "uatrv1": "iron man",
    "uatrt1": "string",
      "uatrk2": "email",
    "uatrv2": "ironman@avengers.com",
    "uatrt2": "string",
      "uatrk3": "age",
    "uatrv3": "32",
    "uatrt3": "integer"
}
    
d["attributes"] = {}
d["traits"] = {}
keys_to_remove = []
for k in d.keys():
    if k.startswith("atrk"):
        value_key = k.replace("atrk","atrv")
        type_key = k.replace("atrk","atrt")
        d["attributes"][d[k]] = {"value":d[value_key],"type":d[type_key]}
        keys_to_remove += [value_key,k,type_key]
    if k.startswith("uatrk"):
        keys_to_remove.append(k)
        value_key = k.replace("uatrk","uatrv")
        type_key = k.replace("uatrk","uatrt")
        d["traits"][d[k]] = {"value":d[value_key],"type":d[type_key]}
        keys_to_remove += [value_key,k,type_key]

for k in keys_to_remove:
    if k in d:
        del d[k]
```

Comment: Hi, as I said this is a part of a bigger JSON file. Your method is yielding results but, it is creating additional key-value pairs and the old ones still remain in the file. @Robin

Comment: If you don't want the old data. How about replaying the file content with new results?

Comment: I have updated the code. But now it seems like I hardcoded a lot. I don't know about the complete dataset. Let me know if this code not worked.

Comment: Hi, I have converted the keys into a list and later used del method to delete the unwanted items. Thanks for for the solution above. @robin

Comment: your previous solution worked fine for me. As I said I used it in combination with the delete method. Can you change your solution back to the previous one? I think it is more effective if we are working with dynamic changes.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code it will successfully convert it.

```
json1={
"atrk1": "form_varient",
    "atrv1": "red_top",
    "atrt1": "string",
      "atrk2": "ref",
    "atrv2": "XPOWJRICW993LKJD",
    "atrt2": "string"
}
json2={}
keys=[]
values=[]
types=[]
for i in json1:
    if i[:4]=='atrk':
        keys.append(json1[i])
        values.append([])
        types.append([])
    elif i[:4]=='atrv':
        values[int(i[-1:])-1].append(json1[i])
    elif i[:4]=='atrt':
        types[int(i[-1:])-1].append(json1[i])

for i in range(len(keys)):
    json2[keys[i]]={
        'value':values[i],'type':types[i]
    }

json3={}
json3['attributes']=json2
print(json3)
```

Comment: unfortunately, i cannot use this as keys with the name prefix "atrk" change dynamically.